# Find the sum of the following series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Find the sum of the following series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1) \frac{1}{n}\frac{9}{6^n}.
$$
I think that $r$ is $\frac{9}{6^n}$ and $a$ is $-1$. But I'm not positive if I'm starting this problem right.

Comment: Don't you mean from 1 to infinity?

Comment: Yes, I do. Sorry about that.

Comment: Do you mean the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty-\frac9{n6^n}\;\;?$$

Comment: ...or this one $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^n\frac{9}{n6^n}$?

Comment: This sum is a [polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

Answer (score 2):

We want to compute the following sum:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\alpha}{nz^n}
$$

where $\alpha,z\in\mathbb C\;$ (in our case $\alpha=-9$ and $z=6$).
We immediately see that $|z|>1$, in order to have absolute convergence.

We recall first two results:

**First:**
$$
\log(1+z)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{z^n}{n},\;\;\;\forall |z|<1
$$
**Second:**
$$
\prod_{n=0}^{+\infty}\left(1+z^{2^{n}}\right)=
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}z^{n}=\frac{1}{1-z},\;\;\;\forall |z|<1
$$
The last one can be proved, showing by induction that $\prod_{k=0}^{N}\left(1+z^{2^{k}}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{2^{N+1}-1}z^{k}$.

Ok:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{nz^n}=&
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^n\\
=&\underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2k+1}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^{2k+1}-
\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2k}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^{2k}}_{\log\left(1+\frac{1}{z}\right)}+
2\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2k}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^{2k}\\
=&\log\left(1+\frac{1}{z}\right)+
\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k}\left(\frac{1}{z^2}\right)^{k}\\
=&\log\left(1+\frac{1}{z}\right)+
\log\left(1+\frac{1}{z^2}\right)+\cdots\\
=&\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{z^{2^n}}\right)\\
=&\log\left(\prod_{n=0}^{+\infty}\left(1+\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^{2^n}\right)\right)\\
=&\log\left(\frac{z}{z-1}\right)
\end{align*}

Hence
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{-9}{n6^n}=-9\log(6/5)\;.
$$

If otherwise you mean to sum
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n9}{n6^n}
$$
it's simpler because you have to deal with 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\alpha(-1)^n}{nz^n}
$$
and
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{nz^n}&
=-\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^n\\
&=-\log\left(1+\frac{1}{z}\right)
\end{align*}
so the sum is
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n9}{n6^n}=-9\log(7/6)\;.
$$

Comment: Monsieur Joe, à vos séries et à vos vaches, je dis: *bravo!*

Comment: Je suis commosso